# Strat tabs from QTabWidget in threads

Tags: qt, qthread, qtextedit, qtabwidget

is it possible to start tabs from the QTabWidget in several threads?
I want to append the continuous given answers from a server to a QTextEditWidget. The change of the QTextEditWidget should show always after the append of a new answer. Acctually i do this with `QApplication::processEvents()`. It works but not asynchron and very slow...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only main thread can interact with GUI objects, therefore
you should create a signal in your Thread class, and create a slot in some object which lives in main thread which will add tabs to QTabWidget. Then simply connect them.